# Change whole block html with php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm running a pretty large drupal 7 website.

I'd like to implement esi support on blocks by wrapping each block content with  tags.

Now I can do that pretty easilly with theme_preprocess or hook_block_view_alter, but this only works if the block "content" variable passed to the drupal template is a string. If that variable is an array for instance it's imposible to wrap it in those tags, because this array is parsed in the template.

So the only way I could get it working is after getting the block value returned from the template. But I don't think the damn drupal even supports that... without hacking the core and outputting the  tags before and after template incluision.
But I really don't want that... so does anybody have an idea how would I be able to achieve this goal ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: obviously how would I achieve the goal described in the article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the block content is an array you can add a `#prefix` and `#suffix` to it:

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if (is_array($data['content']) {
    $data['content']['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-class">';
    $data['content']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
  else {
    $data['content'] = '<div class="my-class">' . $data['content'] . '</div>';
  }
}
```

The `#prefix` and `#suffix` will be honoured for any Drupal render array when it's passed through `render()` (or `drupal_render()`) so this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. That does help on some blocks.. but it does not work on some in which I just iterate through the array without calling drupal render.
I assume I'll just have to change those then...but that's just my fault I guess.